# Pokemon JSON If Statement Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

So I'm currently working with the PokeAPI to make a functional Pokedex.
Pokemon can have 1+ types, so I wrote an if statement to deal with that possibility by using the hasOwnProperty selector.

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("types[1].type.name")) {
    type.innerHTML = "Types: " + data.types[0].type.name + ", " + data.types[1].type.name;
  } else {
    type.innerHTML = "Type: " + data.types[0].type.name;
  }
```

However, the code doesn't seem to work, and it defaults to the "else" portion of the if statement. Could anyone pinpoint the error in my code? Thanks!

This is an example of what the types object looks like:

```
"types": [
    {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3/",
            "name": "flying"
        }
    },
    {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/",
            "name": "fire"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: please, show an example of the `data` variable and also an example of `types[1].type`.
`hasOwnProperty()` you pass the property name, not the entire path to the property as a string like you did

Comment: `data` probably doesn't have a property explicitly called `"types[1].type.name"`, but rather types[n].type.name

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` works only for the object it is called on, you can't look for nested properties like that.

Comment: actually, if I understood correct, you want to check if a single pokemon have more than one type, right? If yes, why not to use `if (data.types.length > 1)`  ?  then if it's bigger, loop through the types concating the type.name ?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [Calvin Nunes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50220212/691711#comment-87457895),

Instead of using `hasOwnProperty()` which does not work when there are a variable number of types in the types object, it's easier to just check if there is more than 1 types with `if (data.types.length > 1){}`.

Comment: Or even better: he doesn't need to check the length it if he is going to do the same action if data have 1 or more types... he just need to loop until the end of types length and keep concatenating... He can go by the simple `for` loop or like said in another answer, by `map`

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to use is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will convert your array of objects into an array of names quite easily.  You can just use this: `'Types: ' + data.types.map(t => t.type.name).join(', ')` to get the snippet you want to add to the HTML.  This is much simpler than mucking around with lengths or `hasOwnProperty`.

```js
const data = {"types": [{"slot": 2, "type": {"name": "flying", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3/"}}, {"slot": 1, "type": {"name": "fire", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/"}}]}

const run = document.getElementById('run')
const types = document.getElementById('types')

run.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  types.innerHTML = 'Types: ' + data.types.map(t => t.type.name).join(', ')
})
```

```html
<p id="types">(empty until you click "Run")</p>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

When you click the button in that snippet, the data is mapped to get the names, and they're joined into your expected string.  Now, if your array has three elements, or seventeen, this will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking a string for `data.hasOwnProperty`

I think this might work for you:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(types[1].type.name)) {
    type.innerHTML = "Types: " + data.types[0].type.name + ", " + data.types[1].type.name;
  } else {
    type.innerHTML = "Type: " + data.types[0].type.name;
  }
```

This checks the actual value of `types[1].type.name` and not the string `"types[1].type.name"`. Hope that helps...